# reduction when allocating daata on the device

Tags: openacc

I have a simple nbody implementation code. To be short, I dropped out the extra code in `randomizeBodies()`.

```
typedef struct
{ 
  float x; 
  float y; 
  float z;
  float w;
} Point4;
n=16384;
Point4  positions   [n];
Point4  velocities  [n];
Point4  acceleration[n];
float   E_pot       [n];
#pragma acc declare device_resident(positions,velocities,
acceleration,E_pot,n)
void randomizeBodies()
{
  float K=0;
  #pragma acc data copy(K)
  #pragma acc parallel loop reduction(+:K)
  for(int i=0;i<n; ++i)
  {
    ...
    Point4 velocity=...;
    K+=1;
    K+=velocity.y*velocity.y;
    K+=velocity.z*velocity.z;
    velocities[i].x = velocity.x ;
    velocities[i].y = velocity.y ;
    velocities[i].z = velocity.z ;
  }
  printf("K=%f",K); 
}
```

Here `veleocity.x`, `velocity.y`, `velocity.z` are float. I call `randomizeBodies()` in `main()` and don't understand why the output writes "K=0". Is anything wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this, it looks like you're managing "K" via a unstructured data region but haven't copied it back to the host before printing.  Try adding an "#pragma acc update self(K)" directive before the print statement.  Alternatively, you can remove the "#pragma acc enter data(K)" statement in which case the compiler will implicitly copy back K after the end of the parallel loop.